# Intervention Image Laravel lose image quality while resizing it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, image-resizing

below is my code for resize image using laravel image intervention,

```
$photo='original image path' // this image is 10kx10k and size is 10 mb
$widthMedium = 1000;
$heightMedium = 1000;

$imgMedium  = Image::make($photo)->resize($widthMedium, $heightMedium, function ($constraint) {
   $constraint->aspectRatio();
   $constraint->upsize();
})->encode($extension, 100);

Storage::put('path to store resized image', $imgMedium, 'public'); // now i got 1kx1k image resize in folder but it's just around 100kb with bad quality
```

Comment: If width and height of uploaded image are less than sizes that you mentioned in your code, of course resized image will be saved in storage with less quality.

Comment: @EHFShahab i know, but problem is, i need to maintain image quality while resizing it... how to get rid of it, if any idea using other third-party of lib, please share 